# How do I forward a text with a link?

Tags: sms, 5.1-lollipop, motorola-moto-e, hyperlinks

I'm using Motorola Moto E (first gen) running Android 5.1.

I'm fairly new to Android, I know I could forward message if I tap and press on the message for a while, wait for the dropdown menu to pop up and then tap on "Message".

The problem is, if there is a link in the message body, no matter where I tap on the message - it gets me to that website instead of showing this context menu.

How do I forward this type of text?

Comment: Long pressing may give you an option to select all and copy?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, messages without links, press->hold->forward. But messages with links 95% of the time I cannot get the press->hold menu up, either get nothing or it opens the browser with the link (normally spam). The weird thing is, every no and then the menu will popup, but I have just been trying to the last 20mins on the latest one and it worked once, caught me by surprise and I can not replicate it again.

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OS hasn't visited the site after posting the question, and no answers have been upvoted). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

Just long press on the message, its should either highlight and give you the option of forwarding or select text, then just select all and paste it on a new message body

Answer (score 0):

Long press on the text, then drag the arrows until you have highlighted the text you want. Then select the bit with the 3 vertical dots and select share.

This only works with text you are not editing. I.e when im typing this awnser out I cant see the share option because im in text edit mode. But if i do it on the text if your questions then I can access the share option.

Answer (score -1):

We can able to do that by long pressing the message which(blank space) below the human face.